# Spring Boot flash attributes not sending on Azure

Tags: spring, spring-boot, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

We have a problem with sending flash attributes.
We test the flash attributes locally and it works.
But after we deployed to Azure, the flash attribute doesn't work.

The app uses Spring Boot and Thymleaf!

Maybe Azure disable this function?
We don't know it.

Java class method:

```java
public void handleInvitationResult(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, InvitationResult invitationResult) {
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("success", invitationResult.isSuccess());
    if (!invitationResult.isSuccess()) {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("exception", invitationResult.getErrorMessage());
    }
}
```

Html Thymleaf file:

```xml
<div th:if="${success}" class="mt-3">
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
        <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle pr-2"></i><span th:text="#{invitation.success}"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**FOUND THER SOLUTION:**

Found the issue, we had to update Spring Boot: 2.3.5.RELEASE -> 2.5.4

Comment: Please post code as code not as images, as those are unreadable.

Comment: I copy the code but I can't copy the whole file. 
But the problem is not with the code.

It is working locally and we tried to run with docker and working as well.

Comment: Flash attributes, depend on sessions (by default) using azure you might have multiple instances, and after a redirect you might end up at a different instance which doesn't have the session and thus no session attributes. Either use a different flash implementation (cookies for instance, although you would need to write them yourself) or configure azure to use sticky sessions (i.e. route to the same server over and over based on the session cookie).

Comment: We don't have multiple instances and we don't use a load balancer.

Comment: We turn on the ARR affinity as well but still not working.

Comment: Found the issue, we had to update Spring Boot: 2.3.5.RELEASE -> 2.5.4

Answer (score 0):

Thank you  [geri100](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9479430/geri100) Glad to hear that you resolved your issue. Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

**After upgrading spring Boot version from `2.3.5 Release` to `2.5.4`** is resolved your issue.